# Creating @RestClientTest test without @SpringBootTest gives error : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration"

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-test

I would like to create a Unit Test for a class which has dependency on RestTemplate and is doing REST calls:

```
public class SOClient { 

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    ... // constructor etc
    public Questions getQuestions() {
        ResponseEntity<Questions[]> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://some-api.com", Questions[].class);
        ...
}
```

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot.
I have created a test which looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest({SOClient.class})
public class SOClientTest {
 
   public void test(){}
}
```

So I followed exactly the example from the tutorial, but I am getting an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a
> @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or
> @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

I do not want to add @SpringBootTest annotation because I do not want to load database-layer etc. I would like to only setup the basics needed for my specific test not the whole Spring Context.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev 1.8